# send_data not sending png data right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, png

I am working on a Rails site that creates dynamic svg images and lets the user download the image they make as a png file. I have a button in the view that posts to the download method in the controller.  My first issue was it is not getting the svg data set in `@Circuit`, but I set it up to read a file with the svg in it for now.

Using the image, it downloads a png file but it is less then 1k and does not open right when try to look at it. I have tested writing the image to a file on a local sever and it works, and the image opens right, so the trouble has to be with the way I have `send_data` setup

```
 def download
   before = Magick::Image.read("circuit.png").first {format="png"}
   blob = before.to_blob
   png = Magick::Image.from_blob(blob)
   # png = Magick::Image.from_blob(@Circuit)
   # send_data png[0], :type => 'image/png', :disposition => 'attachment'

   # test Magick::Image
   # png[0].write("circuit-download.png")

   #test send_data
   test='<body>Hello World</body>'
   send_data test, :type => 'text/html', :disposition => 'inline'
 end
```

Comment: Can you try sending the blob?  `send_data blob, type: "image/png", disposition: "attachment"`

Comment: @steakchaser yeah I tried that and tried to send "before" also

Comment: I just tested this out with the following `    img = Magick::Image.read(Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/logo.png")).first {format="png"}
    send_data img.to_blob, type: "image/png", disposition: "attachment"`.  Works fine.  This was with rmagick 2.13.1

Comment: ok, it is something in the way I am converting from svg to png, because loading a png and using send_data like you show does work. Thank you for helping me to see where my bug is. I am using rmagick 2.13.1 also

Comment: @steakchaser this works to load svg file and send as png:'code'def download
     
     img=Magick::Image.read("circuit.svg").first {format="svg"}
     img.format = 'PNG'
     send_data img.to_blob ,type: "image/png" , disposition: "attachment"
     
   end 'code' but it is not using the stylesheet I use for my webfonts... but thank you for your help

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  Post your code as the answer so others can see the solution more easily.  I've been looking at doing some svg -> png stuff as well for emailing Highcharts content to my customers.

Answer (score 0):

have not been able to get it to use the svg in @Circuit, but I have got it to be able to save the content of @Circuit as a svg file, then convert to and download as png file:

```
def download

 img=Magick::Image.read("circuit.svg").first {format="svg"}
 img.format = 'PNG'
 send_data img.to_blob ,type: "image/png" , disposition: "attachment"
 end
```